# axis.text does not change angle

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis

I understand that in order to change the angle of x-axis we should use `theme() and axis.text.x=element_text(size=1, angle=90)`

For the plot, I used `geom_col` because my x-axis is not a continuous variable, just categories. Could anyone let me know what I did wrong or missed? Something must be obvious for `R` and `ggplot` savvy users! Thank you!

```
data("diamonds")
example_df <- diamonds[unique(diamonds$clarity), ]

ggplot(example_df, aes(reorder(clarity, -carat, sum), carat)) +
  geom_col() + 
  xlab("clarity")+
  ylab("carat") +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(size=1, angle=45)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept=0.2, linetype="dashed", color = "red") +
  ggtitle("test") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Calling `theme_bw()` at the end resets all the `theme` changes you previously added in. Only the last value survives. Just change the order in which you set the values

```
ggplot(example_df, aes(reorder(clarity, -carat, sum), carat)) +
  geom_col() + 
  xlab("clarity")+
  ylab("carat") +
  geom_hline(yintercept=0.2, linetype="dashed", color = "red") +
  ggtitle("test") +
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(size=1, angle=45))
```

Comment: AHHHHHHHH THANK YOU!!! I had this issue before and switched the order and got it to work. But I did not really know it's the order of the `theme_bw()` causing the issue. Thanks very much!